# How to filter dates with double curly brackets?

Tags: r, function, date, curly-braces

Similar to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718274/how-to-use-double-curly-brackets-in-r-with-ggplot-and-dates) about double curly brackets within ggplot, I'm also struggling with using double curly brackets with filtering dates generally. In this function, users can specify a time period (week, month) and then the function filters based on the respective time period. For instance, selecting 'month' should cause the function to focus just on the `Month` and `Month_score` columns. However, it keeps failing and providing incorrect output:

Here's my sample data along with 2 attempts that I made:

```
#Sample data

library(dplyr)
library(lubdridate)

test <- tibble(Week = seq(as.Date("2014-09-04"), by = "week", length.out = 8),
               Month = ymd(rep('2014-09-01', 4), rep('2014-10-01', 4)),
               Week_score = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9),
               Month_score = c(15, NA, NA, NA, 29, NA, NA, NA))
```

Attempt 1--no columns are removed (which is incorrect):

```
date_filter <- function(data, time_period = c("Week", "Month"), start_date = NA_Date_) {


  data %>%
    filter({{time_period}} > start_date)
}

date_filter(data = test, time_period = "Week", start_date = '2014-09-06')
```

Attempt 2: I explicitly callout that start_date is a date, but I get the below error

```
date_filter <- function(data, time_period = c("Week", "Month"), start_date = NA_Date_) {


  data %>%
    filter({{time_period}} > as.Date(start_date))
}

date_filter(data = test, time_period = "Week", start_date = '2014-09-06')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{}}` is meant to be used on unquoted variable names, not on strings.

Remove the `""` from `time_period` when calling your function, and it  works:

```r
date_filter <- function(data, time_period, start_date = NA_Date_) {
  
  
  data %>%
    filter({{time_period}} > as.Date(start_date))
}

date_filter(data = test, time_period = Week, start_date = '2014-09-06')

#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   Week       Month      Week_score Month_score
#>   <date>     <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 2014-09-11 2014-09-01          3          NA
#> 2 2014-09-18 2014-09-01          4          NA
#> 3 2014-09-25 2014-09-01          6          NA
#> 4 2014-10-02 2014-10-01          5          29
#> 5 2014-10-09 2014-10-01          7          NA
#> 6 2014-10-16 2014-10-01          8          NA
#> 7 2014-10-23 2014-10-01          9          NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

rlang has a nice [article](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html) which I recommend everybody to read before working with `{{}}`.

##### Why does `time_period = "Week"` work in the first function but not in the other?

Because `{{time_period}}` gets interpreted as a string, and not the variable `Week`. You quite literally are trying to compare `"Week" > "2014-09-06"` in the first function (which is always `TRUE`), and `"Week" > as.Date("2014-09-06")` in the second function (which makes R want to convert `"Week"` into a date, and thus you get an error).

Answer (score 1):

If we want to pass either quoted or unquoted, then convert to `sym` with `ensym`

```
date_filter <- function(data, time_period = c("Week", "Month"), 
      start_date = NA_Date_) {

  time_period <- rlang::ensym(time_period)
  data %>%
    filter(!!time_period > start_date)
}
```

-testing

```
> date_filter(data = test, time_period = "Week", start_date = '2014-09-06')
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  Week       Month      Week_score Month_score
  <date>     <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2014-09-11 2014-09-01          3          NA
2 2014-09-18 2014-09-01          4          NA
3 2014-09-25 2014-09-01          6          NA
4 2014-10-02 2014-10-01          5          29
5 2014-10-09 2014-10-01          7          NA
6 2014-10-16 2014-10-01          8          NA
7 2014-10-23 2014-10-01          9          NA
> 
> date_filter(data = test, time_period = Week, start_date = '2014-09-06')
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  Week       Month      Week_score Month_score
  <date>     <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2014-09-11 2014-09-01          3          NA
2 2014-09-18 2014-09-01          4          NA
3 2014-09-25 2014-09-01          6          NA
4 2014-10-02 2014-10-01          5          29
5 2014-10-09 2014-10-01          7          NA
6 2014-10-16 2014-10-01          8          NA
7 2014-10-23 2014-10-01          9          NA
```